# Filter git log by author or branch

Tags: git, branch, git-log, author, git-history

In my workflow I'm usually only interested in my own branches and some specific branches like `staging` or `master` and would like my `git log` to reflect that. I've come up with this command :

```
git log --branches=staging* --author=my_name
```

The problem is that the `author` and `branches` filters seem to linked with the logical operator `and`, meaning that I can either see all my branches or staging, but not both at the same time.

In other words, I'd like to see only commits where I'm the author AND all the commits of the branch named `staging` branch (regardless of the authors), with one single command.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Not clear what you asking

Comment: @CodeWizard I just added a paragraph to rephrase my question. Is it better ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git will take commit ids from stdin, it's not limited to any precanned set of construction operators and there's no reason to duplicate arbitrary selection logic when the results can be achieved with existing tools.

```
(git rev-list --branches=staging*;git rev-list --all --author=my_name) \
| git log --stdin --no-walk --oneline
```

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I needed. I actually use the `--graph` option to represent the repository tree, so I ended up replacing `--no-walk` by `--graph` (they are mutually exclusive) : `(git rev-list --branches=staging*;git rev-list --all --author=my_name) | git log --stdin --graph --oneline`.